# Question regarding LASSO confidence intervals using selectiveinference package in R

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval, glmnet, lasso-regression

I want to get the confidence intervals for LASSO regression. For this, I used the [selective inference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectiveInference/selectiveInference.pdf) package in R.

The `fixedLassoInf` function in this package provides the confidence intervals for lasso regression for a given value of lambda. Also, we can pass the coefficient vector obtained from `glmnet` package to this function.

The coefficients for LASSO logistic regression for a given lambda using `glmnet` package is as follows:

```
    require(ISLR)

    require(glmnet)
    require(selectiveInference)

  y1 <- Default$default
x1 <- model.matrix(default ~ student + balance + income + student*income, Default)[, -1]

lasso.mod1 <- glmnet(x1,y1, alpha = 1, lambda = 0.0003274549,family='binomial')

lasso.mod$beta

> lasso.mod1$beta
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                             s0
studentYes        -6.131640e-01
balance            5.635401e-03
income             2.429232e-06
studentYes:income  .
```

Then I used the `fixedLassoInf` function in `selective inference` package in R, to get the confidence intervals:

```
y1 <- Default$default

beta = coef(lasso.mod1, x=x1, y=y1, s=lambda/1000, exact=T)
y1= ifelse(y1=="NO",0,1)

out = fixedLassoInf(x1,(y1),beta,lambda,family="binomial",alpha=0.05)
out
```

**However, I am getting following Warning messages:**

**

```
Warning messages:
1: In fixedLogitLassoInf(x, y, beta, lambda, alpha = alpha, type = "partial",  :
  Solution beta does not satisfy the KKT conditions (to within specified tolerances)
2: In fixedLogitLassoInf(x, y, beta, lambda, alpha = alpha, type = "partial",  :
  Solution beta does not satisfy the KKT conditions (to within specified tolerances). You might try rerunning glmnet with a lower setting of the 'thresh' parameter, for a more accurate convergence.
3: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

**

Also as the output I am getting something not correct,

```
Call:
fixedLassoInf(x = x1, y = (y1), beta = beta, lambda = lambda, 
    family = "binomial", alpha = 0.05)

Testing results at lambda = 0.000, with alpha = 0.050

 Var     Coef   Z-score P-value LowConfPt UpConfPt LowTailArea UpTailArea
   1 1142.801  1884.776       1      -Inf  -60.633           0          0
   2    0.386  1664.734       0     0.023      Inf           0          0
   3    0.029  3318.110       0     0.001      Inf           0          0
   4   -0.029 -1029.985       1      -Inf   -0.003           0          0

Note: coefficients shown are partial regression coefficients
```

Based on the warning message, there is a problem with the Karush Kuhn Tucker (KKT) condition.

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Thank you.

Comment: Better yet, why are you trying to get CI from a LASSO model?

Comment: The glmnet package does not provide standard errors. So CI cannot calculate

Comment: It doesn't provide them for a reason, in that it does not really make sense. What are you trying to achieve with CI?

Comment: Just for the inference purposes.

Comment: LASSo is not made for inference, it's main purpose is prediction. You can google the subject and you will find many references for why this isn't done and why it's a bad idea. If you want inference you should choose a different model.

Comment: This is a worthy question: There is a whole literature on inference after model selection, and there are closed-form solutions for adjusting standard errors by conditioning on the event that variables were selected via the LASSO. `selectiveInference` is a package that does just that. I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147109/r-how-to-translate-lasso-lambda-values-from-the-cv-glmnet-function-into-the-s

Answer (score -1):

One of my university teachers always said

> Fitting is an art, not a technique.

What I mean: Do expect that you need manual work for parameter guessing and multiple iterations of fitting. You might even question the method of fitting itself, but let's not go that path.

Anyhow, R will not do the magic of finding the correct model (now: number of parameters for LASSO) for you. From the output you show, you seem to have 4 variables, of which 3 are close to zero, therefore I suggest to start with...

1. Bounding the maximal number of variables in the model, i.e. `dfmax=2` seems a good start
2. Limiting the maximum number of variables ever to be nonzero, e.g. `pmax=2`

The [documentation of glment](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-18/topics/glmnet) further details on other options.

Comment: @student_R123 For more on KKT, I found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162932/big-picture-behind-how-to-use-kkt-conditions-for-constrained-optimization pretty interesting. Please let me know whether you have questions to my suggestion.