# R: How to translate lasso lambda values from the cv.glmnet() function into the selectiveInference package?

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am using the `{selectiveInference}` package to perform post-selection inference using the lasso ("l1 norm"). This package assumes that the lambda is fixed—that is, we determine it beforehand. However, I need to use cross-validation.

[Taylor & Tibshirani (2018)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6097808/) use simulations to show that using cross-validation to determine lambda yields valid inferential statistics, using the `selectiveInference::fixedLassoInf()` method. ([Another paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08866.pdf) proposed a way to deal with a lambda determined by cross-validation, but it doesn't appear to be in the package yet, and the simulations in the 2018 paper perform well enough for me.)

I see that in the documentation it says that `{glmnet}` uses the 1/n lasso parameterization, whereas `{selectiveInference}` uses the common parameterization. The documentation shows how to go from common lambda and transform it to something that `{glmnet}` can use.

**I need to do the opposite: Go from something `cv.glmnet()` gives me, and turn it into the lambda on the common scale that `fixedLassoInf()` wants.**

Specifically, the `{glmnet}` documentation reads:

> Note also that for "gaussian", glmnet standardizes y to have unit variance (using 1/n rather than 1/(n-1) formula) before computing its lambda sequence (and then unstandardizes the resulting coefficients); if you wish to reproduce/compare results with other software, best to supply a standardized y

While `{selectiveInference}` says:

> Estimated lasso coefficients (e.g., from glmnet). This is of length p (so the intercept is not included as the first component). Be careful! This function uses the "standard" lasso objective... In contrast, glmnet multiplies the first term by a factor of 1/n. So after running glmnet, to extract the beta corresponding to a value lambda, you need to use beta = coef(obj,s=lambda/n)[-1]...

For a reproducible example, see the code below.

My question specifically concerns how to adjust this line: `si_lambda <- glmnet_lambda`. That is, **what transformation do I do** to go from a lambda `cv.glmnet()` gives me (I assign this to `glmnet_lambda`) into a lambda that `{selectiveInference}` will use (which I call `si_lambda`)?

My original thought was that, since the documentation says to divide by n, my thinking would be to multiply what `cv.glmnet()` gives me by my sample size. That runs without throwing a warning or an error, but it gives me a lambda of 188.5121, which feels wrong. Apologies if that is the answer and I'm just being dense—but I wanted to make sure I am going from one software to the other in an appropriate manner.

```
library(glmnet)
library(selectiveInference)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1839)

n <- 1000       # sample size
B <- c(0, 1, 0) # intercept 0, beta1 = 1, beta2 = 0
eps_sd <- 1     # sd of the error

# make data
X <- cbind(1, replicate(length(B) - 1, rnorm(n, 0, 1)))
y <- X %*% B + rnorm(n, 0, eps_sd)
dat <- as.data.frame(X[, -1])
dat <- as_tibble(cbind(dat, y))

# get lambda by way of cross-validation
glmnet_lambda <- cv.glmnet(
  x = as.matrix(select(dat, -y)),
  y = dat$y
) %>% 
  getElement("lambda.1se")

# run glmnet with that lambda
m1 <- glmnet(
  x = as.matrix(select(dat, -y)),
  y = dat$y,
  lambda = glmnet_lambda
)

# get coefs from that model, dropping intercept, per the docs
m1_coefs <- coef(m1)[-1]

# what reparameterization do I do here?
si_lambda <- glmnet_lambda

# do post-selection inference with m1
# runs with warning, so I assume parameterized incorrectly -- how to fix?
m2 <- fixedLassoInf(
  x = as.matrix(select(dat, -y)),
  y = dat$y,
  beta = m1_coefs,
  lambda = si_lambda
)
```

And session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1            stringr_1.4.0            dplyr_1.0.6             
 [4] purrr_0.3.4              readr_1.4.0              tidyr_1.1.3             
 [7] tibble_3.1.2             ggplot2_3.3.3            tidyverse_1.3.1         
[10] selectiveInference_1.2.5 MASS_7.3-54              adaptMCMC_1.4           
[13] coda_0.19-4              survival_3.2-11          intervals_0.15.2        
[16] glmnet_4.1-1             Matrix_1.3-3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is required to turn around the example in the documentation of fixedLassoInf; adapting it to your example grants the following code:

```
library(glmnet)
library(selectiveInference)

# Make dataset
set.seed(1839)
n <- 1000       # sample size
B <- c(0, 1, 0) # intercept 0, beta1 = 1, beta2 = 0
eps_sd <- 1     # sd of the error
X <- cbind(1, replicate(length(B) - 1, rnorm(n, 0, 1)))
y <- X %*% B + rnorm(n, 0, eps_sd)

# Cross-validation to find lambda
gfit = cv.glmnet(X[,-1], y) # we need to remove the intercept variable (glmnet will add another one)
lambda = gfit$lambda.min

# Obtain coefficients (properly scaling lambda and removing the intercept coefficient)
(beta = coef(gfit, x=X[,-1], y=y, s=lambda, exact=TRUE)[-1])
# [1]  0.99297607 -0.04300646

# Compute fixed lambda p-values and selection intervals
(out = fixedLassoInf(X[,-1], y, beta, lambda*n))
# Call:fixedLassoInf(x = X[, -1], y = y, beta = beta, lambda = lambda * n)
# 
# Standard deviation of noise (specified or estimated) sigma = 1.012
# 
# Testing results at lambda = 4.562, with alpha = 0.100
# 
# Var   Coef Z-score P-value LowConfPt UpConfPt LowTailArea UpTailArea
# 1  0.998  31.475   0.000     0.945    1.050       0.049      0.049
# 2 -0.048  -1.496   0.152    -0.100    0.032       0.050      0.049
# 
# Note: coefficients shown are partial regression coefficients
```

Comment: The documentation involves taking a given lambda in the selectiveInference formulation and translating it into the glmnet formulation of the lasso. I am interested in the reverse: So my call to `coef()` would involve doing `s = lambda`, and then the lambda would have to be transformed somehow to the selectiveInference formulation. The documentation assumes we have a lambda and need to translate it to glmnet—I have a lambda value from glmnet and need to translate it to selectiveInference.

Comment: You are right. I have now corrected the answer.

Comment: Also, there is a history of users with issues with selectiveInference (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selectiveinference)

Comment: Word, so your read on it, like mine, is to multiply by `n` instead of divide? It's giving me weird-ass lambda values at times. And yeah, one of the reasons I'm making sure I'm doing this correctly is that I'm doing some simulation studies to see if the package performs with valid false positive rates, etc., and I'm running into weird problems doing the multiply-by-n thing.

Comment: Yes, indeed, unscaled lambda seems quite large, but this is just because you got used to the scales handled by glmnet (which uses its own criteria to define lambda and hence generates so much confusion). Make sure to read the details on fixedLassoInf; your simulations may not be measuring what it is actually computed here (it uses partial regression coefficients, for example). Making inference on lasso regression is not straightforward!